# What are common methods for calculating the time dependency of elliptical orbit?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

After playing a game called "Kerbal Space Program" I got interested in orbital mechanics and started messing with [simplified calculations](http://www.dropbox.com/s/eup1wrsc0bp9xfv/KSPequations.pdf) to determine $\Delta v$ requirements. In which I compared two trajectories to get into orbit/land from orbit to see how much it would matter if you would burn vertical or horizontal (Hohmann) at the surface. Graphs of some results can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74kYg.jpg).

However after this I also wanted to know how much time it would take to perform these maneuvers. I assumed that changes in velocity are instantaneous, so this would be equal to the time between the two changes in velocity. For the Hohmann-like-transfer it is simple, since you travel from periapsis tot apoapsis, which takes half of the orbital period (due to symmetry). But for the other transfer, which applies a vertical change in velocity at the surface, it is very difficult (if there is a sidereal rotational velocity). I tried solving it using [Kepler's second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Second_law), given this formula:

$$
r=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos{\theta}} \tag{1}
$$

Since the area underneath the path from $\theta_0$ to $\theta_1$ can be calculated like this:

$$
A_{\theta_0,\theta_1}=\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}{\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta} \tag{2}
$$

Which can be used to determine the amount of time it would take, since the total area of the ellipse would take one orbital period $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu}}$:

$$
t_{\theta_0,\theta_1}=T\frac{\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}{\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta}}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta}}=T\frac{\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}{\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta}}{\pi a^2\sqrt{1-e^2}} \tag{3}
$$

I am not that good at solving integrals, so I both tried to solve it with MATLAB and WolframAlpha, which gave me this as the result:

$$
\int{\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta}=a^2\sqrt{1-e^2}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{1+e}\right)-\frac{e\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin{\theta}}{2(1+e\cos{\theta})}\right) \tag{4}
$$

So:

$$
t_{\theta_0,\theta_1}=\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu}}\left[2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}}{1+e}\right)-\frac{e\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin{\theta}}{1+e\cos{\theta}}\right]^{\theta_1}_{\theta_0} \tag{5}
$$

However when I tried to determine the integral with symbolic parameters and bounderies, MATLAB returned "Warning: Explicit integral could not be found." probably because there is not a general solution for both closed and open orbits. But if I use this formula and filled in the boundaries myself, it seemed that I got wrong results. However when I let MATLAB calculate the integral for given values of $a$, $e$, $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ I do get results which seem correct.

So is this a good approach to find a time dependency of an (elliptical) orbit. If so is there an (continuous) equation derivable from this. And what might be a better approach?

**EDIT 1:** The unexpected results form this formula might be caused by the fact that $\tan^{-1}$ returns results from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Since when I calculated the time from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\pi$ I got results which agree with the conservation of energy and angular momentum.
For this is used the following equations to determine the time derivatives:

$$
\omega=\frac{\delta\theta}{\delta t}=\frac{\delta \theta / \delta \theta}{\delta t / \delta \theta}=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{a^3\left(1-e^2\right)^3}}\left(1+e\cos{\theta}\right)^2 \tag{6}
$$

$$
\dot{r}=\frac{\delta r}{\delta t}=\frac{\delta r / \delta\theta}{\delta t / \delta\theta}=\omega\frac{\delta r}{\delta\theta}=\omega\frac{ae(1-e^2)\sin{\theta}}{\left(1+e\cos{\theta}\right)^2} \tag{7}
$$

Which yields that the specific orbital energy $\epsilon$ and specific angular momentum $h$ are constant when substituting theses therms into there expressions:

$$
\epsilon=\frac{v^2}{2}-\frac{\mu}{r}=\frac{\dot{r}^2+\omega^2r^2}{2}-\frac{\mu}{r}=-\frac{\mu}{2a} \tag{8}
$$

$$
h=\omega r^2=\sqrt{a\mu\left(1-e^2\right)} \tag{9}
$$

**Edit 2:** To show that equation $(5)$ is equivalent to [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) without relying on Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica to do trigonometric simplifications, you can multiply both sides by $\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{a^3}}$, which turns the left hand side into the [mean anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly#Formulae). The first term can easilly be shown to be equal to the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly#From_the_true_anomaly), because the relation between them is defined as

$$
\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1-e}} \tan\frac{E}{2}, \tag{10a}
$$

from which follows

$$
\tan\frac{E}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1-e}{1+e}} \sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1+e}} \tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{1+e} \tan \frac{\theta}{2}, \tag{10b}
$$

$$
E = 2 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{1+e} \tan \frac{\theta}{2}\right). \tag{10c}
$$

For the second term it is a little more work to show that it is equal to minus $e\sin E$. The minus and $e$ can be factored out in both terms, such that we need to prove that

$$
\sin E = \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}\sin{\theta}}{1+e\cos{\theta}}. \tag{11}
$$

The following [trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) will be used:

- $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$
- $\sin 2x = \frac{2 \tan x}{1 + \tan^2 x}$
- $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$
- $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$
- $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$

We have an expression for $\tan\frac{E}{2}$ as a function of $\theta$ from equation $\text{(10a)}$, this will initially be represented by $\alpha$

$$
\sin E = \frac{2 \tan \frac{E}{2}}{1 + \tan^2 \frac{E}{2}} = \frac{2 \alpha}{1 + \alpha^2}. \tag{12a}
$$

Substituting equation $\text{(10b)}$ for $\alpha$ into the last equation yields

$$
\sin E = \frac{2 \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{1+e} \tan \frac{\theta}{2}}{1 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{1+e} \tan \frac{\theta}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{2 \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2}}{1+e} \frac{\sin \frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}}{1 + \frac{1-e^2}{(1+e)^2} \frac{\sin^2\!\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos^2\!\frac{\theta}{2}}} = \frac{2 \sqrt{1-e^2} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}}{(1+e) \cos^2\!\frac{\theta}{2} + (1-e) \sin^2\!\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2} \sin \theta}{\cos^2\!\frac{\theta}{2} + \sin^2\!\frac{\theta}{2} + e \left(\cos^2\!\frac{\theta}{2} - \sin^2\!\frac{\theta}{2}\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2} \sin \theta}{1 + e \cos\theta}. \tag{12b}
$$

So this shows that equation $\text{(11)}$ is true and equation $\text{(5)}$ is equivalent to Kepler's equation.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_mechanics#Calculating_trajectories , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_Equation

Comment: @BenCrowell these Wikipedia pages suggest that there is no finite equation which describe an orbit (so an infinite sum of therms does not suffice). The equation I came up with is, however there does not seems to be an inverse function, so there is no equation for the position as a function of time, but there is an equation for the time as a function of the position. But I wonder if anyone else has come up with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to Kepler's equation, just in terms of true anomaly $\theta$ instead of eccentric anomaly $E$. Read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Computing_position_as_a_function_of_time).

$\tan \frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1 + e}{1 - e}} \tan \frac{E}{2} \\
E = 2 \tan^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{1 - e}{1 + e}} \tan \frac{\theta}{2} \right) = 2 \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\sqrt{1 - e^2}}{1 + e} \tan \frac{\theta}{2} \right) \\
n t = M = E - e \sin E \\
t = \frac{P}{2 \pi} ( E - e \sin E )$

Having [Wolfram Alpha or Mathematica do the trig simplification](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5BTrigToExp%5BSin%5B2+ArcTan%5BTan%5Btheta%2F2%5D+Sqrt%5B1-e%5E2%5D+%2F+%281%2Be%29%5D%5D%5D%5D), 
we get (moving $i$ inside the square root)

$\sin E = \frac{\sqrt{1-e^2} \sin \theta}{1 + e \cos \theta}$

Comment: Thank you, I had an hard time finding a similar equation for time as a function of the position, which seemed odd, since this wasn't that hard to derive.