# Respective displacements of two rest planets and their displacement functions when colliding due to gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, astrophysics

Suppose two and only two planets with point masses are colliding due to gravity. I am trying to solve for

1. Final displacement of the two planets
2. Time-dependent displacement functions of the two planets

By Newton's Gravitational Law, $\displaystyle F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$ where $r$ is the distance between the two positions of the planet. The core problem is that $F$ or the acceleration increases as distance $r$ decreases.

Let the following variables:

- $m_1,m_2$: mass of the two planets respectively
- $s_{f1},s_{f2}$: final displacements of the two planets respectively
- $s_1(t), s_2(t)$: displacement functions of the two planets respectively
- $r_0$: initial distance of the two planets
- $r(t)$: time-dependent total distance between the planets

---

Is the ratio of displacements of the two planets always negatively equal to the inverse ratio of mass of the two planets? Here is what I did: ($u$ is a dummy variable)
$$m_1\frac{d^2s_1}{dt^2}=-m_2\frac{d^2s_2}{dt^2}$$
$$m_1\int^t_0\int^u_0\Big(\frac{d^2s_1}{dt^2}\Big)dt=-m_2\int^t_0\int^u_0\Big(\frac{d^2s_2}{dt^2}\Big)dt$$
$$m_1s_1\Big|^t_0=-m_2s_2\Big|^t_0$$
$$\frac{m_1}{m_2}=-\frac{s_2\Big|^t_0}{s_1\Big|^t_0}$$
If that is the case then $\displaystyle s_{f1}=r_0\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}$ and $\displaystyle s_{f2}=r_0\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}$

---

How do I find $s_1(t)$ and $s_2(t)$ analytically? I currently can think of two separate approaches:

1. $$\frac{\partial ^2s_1}{\partial t^2}=G\frac{m_2}{(r_0-s_1-s_2)^2}$$
   $$\frac{\partial ^2s_2}{\partial t^2}=G\frac{m_1}{(r_0-s_1-s_2)^2}$$
2. $$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=\frac{G(m_1+m_2)}{(r_0-r)^2}$$
   and then use the displacement ratio proved above to find the respective displacement functions.

How do I solve the differential equations analytically?

Comment: $s_1$ and $s_2$.....  what?  What's with $s$?

Comment: @JEB $s_1$ and $s_2$ are variable displacements of planet 1 and planet 2 respectively. The same goes for all variables. My question should has no $s$.

Comment: what is their support?

Comment: @JEB what do you mean

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102269/position-of-two-bodies-as-a-function-of-time-special-case

Comment: @BowlOfRed Thanks for the reference, that answers my second question. How about the displacement ratio?

Comment: Are each $s$ 1, 2, or 3 dimensional?

Comment: @JEB one dimensional. (This should be a one dimensional problem right? Since it's just about planets colliding together by travelling on a straight line)