# Computing 2d Orbital Parameters

Tags: orbital-motion

When using [formulas](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/2d-orbital-path-from-state-vectors) that describe a 2d orbit around a planetary body:

- is it actually OK for the semi-major axis $a$ to be negative?
- when $a$ is negative, it is impossible to compute mean anomaly from time, so what is the equivalent of mean anomaly for parabolic or hyperbolic orbits, assuming that $a$ can be negative?

Comment: No, it is **definitely** not okay for your semi-major axis to be negative for the same reasons you cannot have a negative radius.

Comment: So then how do I compute semi-major axis $a$ for a parabolic/hyperbolic orbit (i.e. $e >= 1$)? Would you care to answer?

Comment: You can't for a parabolic orbit (it's an undefined term). For a hyperbolic orbit, you do it the same way as an elliptic orbit: [use geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_axis#Hyperbola).

Comment: But if you evaluate the equation for the semi-major axis, $a=\frac{r\mu}{2\mu-rv^2}$, for $e\geq 1$ you do get negative values. And is you use negative values in other equations which discribe orbital motion, they work just fine.

Comment: @fibonatic if I use $a < 0$, then $\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{a^3}}$, the "slope" of mean anomaly with respect to time, is imaginary. That doesn't work, and that is what my question is all about...

Comment: This is not correct, since the slope should be proportional to [$\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{a^3(1-e^2)^3}}$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69380/what-are-common-methods-for-calculating-the-time-dependency-of-elliptical-orbit) which would be complex for a positive $a$ when $e>1$.