# Universal formulation of Kepler problem for the hyperbolic case

Tags: orbital-motion

I'm trying to derive the universal formulation of the time-of-flight equation that appears in the Kepler problem (following Bate *Fundamentals of astrodynamics* and Vallado *Fundamentals of astrodynamics and applications*), and I don't see a point about the hyperbolic case.

Starting from the energy equation:

$$ \dot{r}^2 = -\frac{\mu p}{r^2} + \frac{2\mu}{r} -\frac{\mu}{a} $$

after a Sundman transformation ($\dot{\chi} = \frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{r}$
) and separating we have

$$ d\chi = \frac{dr}{\sqrt{-p + 2 r - \frac{r^2}{a}}}$$

Then both Bate and Vallado proceed and integrate assuming the elliptic case ($a > 0$), yielding

$$ \chi + c_0 = \sqrt{a} \arcsin{\frac{\frac{r}{a} - 1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{p}{a}}}}$$

**Later it is justified that this formulation is valid for elliptical, parabolic and hyperbolic orbits** using the [Stumpff functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stumpff_function), even though the integration was not performed for the case $a < 0$ ($a = 0$ is trivial). Furthermore, Vallado states "this case results in a hyperbolic sine solution, which we won't use" but after several trials I got a hyperbolic cosine solution instead:

$$ \chi + c_0 = \sqrt{-a} \cosh^{-1}{\frac{\frac{r}{-a} + 1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{p}{a}}}}$$

I expected a sinh though, to keep simmetry with the other case.

My main question is: **how come can you start from a certain case and then prove the formulation is valid for all of them**? And as an aside: how would the hyperbolic derivation be?

<strike><sub>Note: I know Battin *An Introduction to the Mathematics and Methods of Astrodynamics* has probably more detailed math but there's no way I can get one until the end of the holidays.</sub></strike>

Comment: [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69380/what-are-common-methods-for-calculating-the-time-dependency-of-elliptical-orbit) is maybe a related question. And to answer your main question, I would suggest testing it. For example comparing it to a numerical simulation, such as ode45.

Comment: Are you familiar with the complex relation $\sinh ix=i\sin x$? This implies $i\sinh^{-1}x = \sin^{-1}ix$.

Comment: @fibonatic The point is that at the end of the derivation both introduce the Stumpff functions (which work for both positive and negative values of `a`) and then go backwards and show the formulation works for all cases, so in principle it's already tested. Thanks for linking your question but I don't think it's related to mine.

Comment: @Pulsar yes I am, and it's what motivates the definition of the Stumpff functions, but it's of little help at this stage. As I said above, I'm trying to go the inverse path (which, for me, seems the *direct* path).

Comment: All right, I matematically proved it. I'm answering my own question this year or the next :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The hyperbolic cosine solution is actually correct**, contrary to what Vallado seems to state. The key here is in the definition of the Stumpff functions (which Bate calls universal functions with a change of variable).

If we solve for $r$ from the elliptic case result, we have $r = a \left(1 + e \sin{\frac{\chi + c_0}{\sqrt{a}}} \right)$, whereas for the hyperbolic case it is $r = a \left(1 - e \cosh^{-1}{\frac{\chi + c_0}{\sqrt{-a}}} \right)$. Both Bate and Vallado derivate an expression for $r$ in terms of $\chi$ and $\psi = \chi^2 / a$, which is:

$$r = \chi^2 C + \frac{\mathbf{r}_0 \cdot \mathbf{v}_0}{\sqrt{\mu}} \chi (1 - \psi S) + r_0 (1 - \psi C)$$

where $S$ and $C$ are the [second and third Stumpff functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stumpff_function), in this case taking *positive arguments*. **I then followed exactly the same derivation starting from the hyperbolic solution and arrived to the very same equation, with the Stumpff functions taking *negative* arguments this time**. Plus it's easy to see that going from one form to the other only takes using the properties of the complex numbers, and everything works. Problem solved.