# Elliptical orbit: $\theta$ in terms of $t$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Suppose we have an elliptical orbit with the sun at one focus $F_1$ -- See diagram. Let $F_1$ be the origin and let $\theta$ be the the angle between $F_1P$ and $F_1B$. Find $\theta$ as a function of time $t$.

[image]

**My attempt:**

According to Kepler's 2nd law, $$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}r^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}=k\tag1$$

where $k$ is a constant.

We know that $\displaystyle r=\frac{p}{1-\epsilon\cos\theta}$ where $p$ is the semi-latus rectum and $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse.

Substituting into (1), we get

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p}{1-\epsilon\cos\theta}\right)^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}=k$$

We can now integrate to find $\theta$ in terms of $t$.

Is this correct? Is there is a simpler way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, just the angular momentum $l=mr^{2}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is a constant of motion, which relates to the area swept in unit time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are common methods for calculating the time dependency of elliptical orbit?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69380)